# Difference of variable selection and importance estimation

Tags: feature-selection, importance

Isn't variable importance estimation a necessary prerequisite for variable selection? 
Is there any use case where you want to select non-important variables for your model?
So, why is variable selection considered different from variable importance estimation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't variable importance estimation a necessary prerequisite for variable selection?

There's a connection: e.g. excluding predictors with low standardized coefficients during LASSO, excluding predictors with low Wald's chi-squared during a backward stepwise selection. Nevertheless (1) measuring importance in some way or other doesn't tell you where to draw the line between "important" & "unimportant", & (2) the importance of one predictor tends to depend on the coefficients of other predictors in the model, e.g. LASSO paths cross, Wald's chi-squareds change as predictors are removed. So you *could* perform variable selection by simply using a cut-off on an importance measure, but most methods are more complex. Furthermore some variable-selection methods don't obviously involve any kind of importance measure at the level of individual predictors, e.g. comparing AICs across all possible subsets. So no; it's neither necessary nor sufficient in general.

> Is there any use case where you want to select non-important variables for your model?

If you *knew* which predictors had no relationship at all with the response you wouldn't include them to start with. So any feature selection method introduces bias into estimates & predictions which may or may not be offset by a reduction in their variance (hence the importance of validating the model). Data reduction of the predictors & regularization without shrinking coefficients to zero (e.g. ridge regression) are alternatives to feature selection when the full model over-fits.

It's also perhaps worth noting the common enough case where you're interested in the estimates (point & interval) in their own right, & not just in the overall predictive performance of the model. Clearly setting a coefficient to zero isn't estimating it; less obviously the coefficient estimates of predictors kept in the model will become biased when other predictors are excluded. See [Should covariates that are not statistically significant be 'kept in' when creating a model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66448/should-covariates-that-are-not-statistically-significant-be-kept-in-when-creat).

Comment: (+1) Might that final paragraph benefit from a slight expansion? What happens in that case seems to have a direct bearing on the OP's subquestion about in which situations you may deliberately retain unimportant variables.

Comment: Nice edit, and I think that's a particularly helpful link for the OP too.