# When the effect size of a covariate is high and yet not significant

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, feature-selection, predictor

I was reading this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/66459/18192) to the question on whether all covariates should be kept in the model or just those that are statistically significant, and I noticed the point number 2:

> The effect size of a covariate may be high, even if it is not significant.

And, this has always been on my mind, why we could have such a situation. Can you please elaborate this point on why this could happen and maybe a hypothetical example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Significance* means *detectability*.  That, in turn, depends (among other things) on the *amount of data*.  **A common way to see large but insignificant effect sizes, then, is when there isn't much data.**  Since such examples are numerous and easy to create, I won't dwell on this rather uninteresting point.

There are subtler things that can go on.  Even with relatively large amounts of data, **a model can fail to detect an effect because that effect is masked or otherwise confused with another effect.**

H**ere's an example** involving a plain-vanilla linear regression with two explanatory variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ and a response $y$ that is conditionally independent, Normal, and of constant variance--in other words, as beautiful a situation as one could hope for when applying Least Squares methods.

[image: ![Scatterplot matrix]

This scatterplot matrix shows how the three variables are related within a sample of three hundred observations.  Perhaps, for instance, an experimenter was able to observe a system in three different conditions; measured $x_1,x_2,$ and $y$ one hundred times in each condition; and wishes to understand how $y$ might be related to the $x_i$.  That sounds like a typical (and therefore important) situation to understand.

There does seem to be a relationship: although the values of $y$ are spread over ranges of roughly $0-4$, $1-5$, and $2-6$, these ranges shift upwards as the values of the $x_i$ increase from near $-1$ to near $1$.  The regression overall is significant (the p-value is too tiny to be calculated).

Here are the coefficient estimates and their associated statistics:

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.06269    0.05619  54.501   <2e-16
x.1         -1.95875    1.88340  -1.040    0.299    
x.2          2.96594    1.88206   1.576    0.116
```

Notice:

1. The p-values for the coefficients are 0.299 and 0.116.  Neither would be considered "significant" in most situations: they are too large.
2. The coefficient estimates ("effect sizes") of $-1.96$ and $2.97$ are *large*.  What does "large" mean here?  Simply that since each of the $x_i$ varies by more than $1 - (-1)=2$ in the dataset, a coefficient of (say) $2.97$ translates to variations of more than $2\times 2.97\approx 6$ in the prediction of $y$.  Since the total variation in $y$ is only from $0$ to $6$, this means $x_1$ alone can completely determine the value of $y$!  That's large.

This failure-to-detect the effects of the $x_i$ comes about because the $x_i$ separately give us nearly the same information: they are said to be (almost) *collinear*.  Collinearity can be subtle and much more difficult to detect when there are more than two explanatory variables.  [Search our site for more examples.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=multiple%20regression%20collinear)

You may modify this example to explore the effects of sample size, variability, coefficients, and so on.  Here is the `R` code.  Comment out the line `set.seed(17)` when experimenting, so that you get randomly different results each time.

```R
library(data.table)
n <- 100    # One-third of the sample size
tau <- .02  # Conditional standard deviation of the explanatory variables
sigma <- 1  # Error standard deviation
#
# Create data.
#
set.seed(17)                            # Creates reproducible data
x <- c(rep(1,n), rep(0,n), rep(-1,n))   # Experimental "condition"
X <- data.table(x.1=rnorm(3*n, x, tau), # Regressor x.1
                x.2=rnorm(3*n, x, tau)) # Regressor x.2
invisible(X[, y := rnorm(3*n, 3+x+x.2-x.1, sigma)]) # y (including error)
#
# Plot the data.
#
pairs(X, pch=19, col="#00000010")
#
# Perform least squares regression.
#
fit <- lm(y ~ ., X)
summary(fit)
```